# .js Date String YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get a string with date/time on this format: "YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM"
I cannot find a proper way to do it?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
var x = new Date();
var TimeStamp = x.toString();
```

Outputs:

> Tue Oct 30 2018 14:33:03 GMT+0000 (UTC)

Comment: Try a library like moment to format dates

Answer (score 2):

Use [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) methods and format it.

```js
var date = new Date();
var output = date.getFullYear()+'-'+("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)+'-'+("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2)+'-'+date.getHours()+'-'+date.getMinutes()
console.log(output)
```

Or you can use [momentjs format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/format).

```js
console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```